# How to get AWS SAM Lambda TypeScript debugging working in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, vscode-debugger, aws-sam

I can't get local debugging to work for a Lambda written in Typescript.

I'm on macOS Ventura, Docker Desktop 4.21.1, SAM 1.95.0, and Node 18.x. Project was generated with SAM, and the TS version is 4.8.4.

Here's the layout:

[image]

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-ts-pipeline-fn

  Sample SAM Template for sam-ts-pipeline-fn
  
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints: 
        - app.ts

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "strict": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "./build"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.test.ts"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "hello_world",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "hello world sample for NodeJS",
    "main": "app.js",
    "repository": "https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/tree/develop/samcli/local/init/templates/cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-nodejs",
    "author": "SAM CLI",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "unit": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint '*.ts' --quiet --fix",
        "compile": "npx tsc",
        "test": "npm run compile && npm run unit"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "esbuild": "^0.14.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
        "@types/node": "^18.11.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
        "eslint": "^8.8.0",
        "jest": "^29.2.1",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4"
    }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "SAM debug",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 8065,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/hello-world/build",
            "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/hello-world/build/**/*.js"],
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "lambda:HelloWorldFunction (nodejs18.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceRoot}/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "API lambda:HelloWorldFunction (nodejs18.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "api",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceRoot}/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "api": {
                "path": "/hello",
                "httpMethod": "get",
                "payload": {
                    "json": {}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to debug using either of the "direct-invoke" configs, I end up stuck in `async_hooks`:

[image]

The output for template direct-invoke:

> Debugger attached. Could not read source map for
> file:///var/task/app.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/Users/me/Documents/Projects/Learning/aws/projects/sam-pipeline-test/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/hello-world/app.js.map'
> END RequestId: a03c5676-0ac4-45a2-a173-485d29388d05 REPORT RequestId:
> a03c5676-0ac4-45a2-a173-485d29388d05  Init Duration: 0.94 ms  Duration:
> 2940.13 ms    Billed Duration: 2941 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB  {"statusCode": 200, "body": "{"message":"hello
> world"}"}

...and for api direct-invoke:

> Debugger attached. Could not read source map for
> file:///var/task/app.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/Users/me/Documents/Projects/Learning/aws/projects/sam-pipeline-test/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/hello-world/app.js.map'
> END RequestId: 38cc6069-bebe-4bf8-adf6-aaafcededae2 REPORT RequestId:
> 38cc6069-bebe-4bf8-adf6-aaafcededae2  Init Duration: 0.87 ms  Duration:
> 157236.19 ms  Billed Duration: 157237 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB

If I fire this off in the terminal:

```
sam local invoke -e events/event.json --debug-port 8065 HelloWorldFunction
```

...

...then try to use the attach debug config, I end up in this file:
[image]

The terminal output looks like this, at this point:

> Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs18.x)
> Local image is up-to-date
> Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18-rapid-x86_64.                                                                                                                >Mounting
> /Users/me/Documents/Projects/Learning/aws/projects/sam-pipeline-test/sam-ts-pipeline-fn/.aws-sam/build/H
> elloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container
> START RequestId: a3b03e93-712c-4678-8911-b299bb367e57 Version: $LATEST
> Debugger listening on
> ws://0.0.0.0:8065/44b451d9-8773-4244-a300-e4f901a95e07 For help, see:
> https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector Debugger attached. END RequestId:
> a3b03e93-712c-4678-8911-b299bb367e57 REPORT RequestId:
> a3b03e93-712c-4678-8911-b299bb367e57  Init Duration: 0.92 ms
> Duration: 57695.75 ms   Billed Duration: 57696 ms Memory Size: 128 MB
> Max Memory Used: 128 MB {"statusCode": 200, "body":
> "{"message":"hello world"}"}

I've tried a myriad of different options in different posts and blog articles, and everyone seems to do it differently, each claiming success. I've got breakpoints set in app.ts and the build/app.js files (just in case.)

What's the trick?

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @dgokcin Yes...by abandoning SAM and using Serverless Framework, strictly for debugging. I had zero issues and it's quite a bit easier to work with.

Comment: considering SAM is actively being developed, I think they will eventually make typescript support more developer friendly. considering the popularity of typescript, I still think maybe I am missing something or can work around this.

Comment: @dgokcin That was my assessment as well. It's rough. It creates a lot of cruft in a newly created project, is super slow, and TS support seems to be broken. I could be wrong, but I found no help here or anywhere else, and everything I could Google up was old and didn't work. I'm happy to re-evaluate once it improves, but I almost wish they'd abandon it and add its Lambda features into the CDK, since there's so much overlap already.